# Allowing multiple columns to be viewed at same time with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet for my company that allows loan officers to view information for each investor we work with.

I am currently using this code -

```
  Private Sub CheckBox4_Click()
    [j:j].EntireColumn.Hidden = CheckBox4
    [k:m].EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    [n:bc].EntireColumn.Hidden = CheckBox4
```

The above code represents one investor we work with. It closes the column(s) before, and the column(s) after and allows the column to be looked at to stay visible.

What I am after is how do I allow for multiple columns to be viewed at the same time using the code above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.
Dave

Comment: `[k:m].EntireColumn.Hidden = False` keeps columns visible. If you need to specify more columns than that, I'm unsure what's stopping you.

Comment: Hello Big Ben - not sure what is stopping me either. However, I have 3 checkboxes checked but is only allowing me to view the most recently checked column.

Comment: That sounds like the code in the last checkbox is hiding columns you unhid with the previous two checkboxes.

Comment: Big Ben - Any idea on how to change that so multiple columns may be viewed at once with the code given?

Comment: The "given code" is not enough to make us understand **which columns do you want showing in some SPECIFIC circumstances**. So, please edit your question and clearly **explain what is to be done in case of each check box, two of them and all of them**. If not able to explain it in words, place relevant pictures for each case.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a few expressions. Evaluate the expressions based on the current state of multiple checkboxes, and then use that result to determine if each set of columns should be visible or not. Each checkbox should use the same expressions, so each checkbox is not over-writing the others.